# Download Steam games outside of Steam

Tags: steam

Recently, while explaining exactly what Steam is and what its benefits are, someone asked me: "But what happens if Steam went bankrupt all of a sudden and you couldn't access the platform anymore?".

Which got me thinking what would happen in that case. Do you lose ownership of all your games? Or is there currently already a way to claim games you bought on Steam somewhere else?

Comment: It's highly unlikely that Steam will be going anywhere for a while yet, but in the case that it does happened I'd hope they would provide a patch to let you download your games and run everything offline.

Comment: That's one solution, though it might be problematic in case one has an excessive number of games and needs to download and persist all of them in a limited time scope.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about guessing what would happen in a hypothetical scenario and speculation on the future.

Comment: I'm sorry but seeing the quality of the answers I do not believe it's just guessing, I believe it's a valid point of concern that others may have as well.

Comment: Question is a about accessing Steam games without Steam. It has nothing to do with hypothetical scenarios - this is fully covered by Valve legal statements (Steam EULA). These can obviously change in future (as well as Steam going down, etc.), but this matter is not actually discussed here. I believe the question has an educational value, as many users are unaware of such aspects of digital distribution in general.

Comment: @tombull89, If Steam disappears, where would you download them from? Someone still needs to provide those servers and bandwidth. You're more likely to get a free copy from the actual publishers (or studios in the case they're self-publishing) before the actual shutdown, assuming there'd be advance warning.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about matters of law, not playing video games.

Comment: Matters of law are just justification. Question is simple and clear - if and how is it possible to access (and, in consequence, *play*) games bought on Steam without using Steam. It is impossible to answer such question without referring to software (*video game*) license or discussing when need for such access would be needed.

Comment: The question asks what would happen if Valve went bankrupt. We have no way of knowing that, and even if Valve announced a contingency plan in that regard they couldn't be held to it in the event of their bankruptcy. How is that **not** a question about a hypothetical scenario?

Comment: A separate question could be asked of playing Steam games without Steam, but it would be far too broad to be acceptable IMO (no one answer could cover every title, or even a majority of them).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Steam is a digital distribution service platform, which in practice means the games are leased to users only on Steam, without granting them any kind of real ownership or ability to run the software outside of Steam.

In particular, below is an excerpt from Steam Subscription Agreement:

> 2. LICENSES
>
> A. General Software License
>
> Steam and your Subscription(s) require the automatic download and
>   installation of Software onto your computer. Valve hereby grants, and
>   you accept, a limited, terminable, non-exclusive license and right to
>   use the Software for your personal, non-commercial use (except where
>   commercial use is expressly allowed herein or in the applicable
>   Subscription Terms) in accordance with this Agreement, including the
>   Subscription Terms. **The Software is licensed, not sold.** Your license
>   confers no title or ownership in the Software. To make use of the
>   Software, you must have a Steam Account and you may be required to be
>   running the Steam client and maintaining a connection to the Internet.

The Software is defined at the beginning of the license:

> 1. REGISTRATION AS A SUBSCRIBER; APPLICATION OF TERMS TO YOU; YOUR ACCOUNT
>
> Steam is an online service offered by Valve.
>
> You become a subscriber of Steam ("Subscriber") by installing the
>   Steam client software and completing the Steam registration. This
>   Agreement takes effect as soon as you indicate your acceptance of
>   these terms.
>
> As a Subscriber you may obtain access to certain services, software
>   and content available to Subscribers. **The Steam client software and
>   any other software, content, and updates you download or access via
>   Steam, including but not limited to Valve or third-party video games
>   and in-game content, and any virtual items you trade, sell or purchase
>   in a Steam Subscription Marketplace** are referred to in this Agreement
>   as **“Software”**; the rights to access and/or use any services, Software
>   and/or content accessible through Steam are referred to in this
>   Agreement as "Subscriptions."

Source: http://store.steampowered.com/subscriber_agreement/

In case of retail games requiring Steam to play, Steam is in practice a DRM system, which aims to eliminate piracy and game trading in exchange for a host of online features (multiplayer, achievements, updates, etc.).

Again, to reiterate - there is no game ownership here, you do not physically own the game. What Steam users own is the right to use the software on Steam as defined in license, and there is no automatic/built-in way to play the games outside of Steam (some developers may grant such possibilities, but it is not a concern of Steam/Valve).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Doesn't the Software in this case refer to the Steam client?

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: You might also want to see this question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82529/what-will-happen-to-my-digital-games-after-i-die

Comment: Ouch. That's harsh if you think about it. Let's just hope they never close up shop :)

Comment: Steam appears rock solid currently, but there are quite a large number of smaller digital distribution services, and these seem more risky. But again, it's a problem for every kind of online-provided content.

Comment: The note about licensed and not sold is not really referring to this situation, it is rather explaining that you do not become the owner of the software with the rights to request source or distribute etc, you are only allows to use it under the publisher's license agreement. I do not think that comment is trying to stipulate what would happen if the platform became unavailable.

Comment: @Vality interesting point, though almost every EULA out there (including physical copies of games sold at retail) does not grant the buyer permission to access source code, distribute, public play, modify, reverse engineer etc. the actual software, and only permits usage as defined in license agreement. Issues with digital distribution and no offline content are not virtual - Games for Windows Live titles, unless specifically patched by developers, will likely be unplayable after the service is turned off (expected this year). This also already happened for retail online-only console games.

Comment: To extend on this answer, in general no software is ever sold. Software is only ever licensed, no matter the distribution platform. The idea that you go to a shop and buy a copy of a game and it is yours is a pretty common fallacy. You go to the shop, purchase a disc which comes with the right to use the software on the disc. If you lose the CD, you usually lose the right to use the software and need to buy another copy. If Steam were to go under, it's analogous to losing your disc, almost exactly.

Comment: Ironically, this is where I think things like UPlay and Origin actually help the situation (as long as cross-polination actually happens; EA, I'm looking at you). If I buy a recent Ubisoft title on Steam it gets routed via UPlay. I now 'own' the software in two locations: I can either install it via Steam or UPlay and then play it. If either Valve or Ubisoft goes under then I can still get it from the other.

Comment: @MatthewScharley exactly, in a way Steam is like a guy who will keep all your CDs, providing along some secondary services. It gives convenience and storage in exchange for lesser control and dependence on communication (in this case - Internet). However, having more than one of such guys (e.g. Steam and GfWL) is not always good - some games require connectivity to BOTH systems (e.g. launching game on Steam triggers connection to GfWL). I still wait what will happen to my FlatOut: Ultimate Carnage or Mortal Kombat Kollection...

Comment: @acalypso: In the case of Ubi, the requirement (reads: DRM) is via UPlay, but if you install via Steam it'll still launch via Steam. It's actually quite well done in my opinion. The case of GfWL is unfortunate; given that it's actually entirely a library provided by Microsoft, one would hope that they would release an update to GfWL itself that replaces the login with a NOP. We can dream anyway.

Comment: @MatthewScharley it might not be that easy from what I investigated. It seems GfWL support is programmed directly into game code, so each game needs its own patch. This could be done centrally on the Steam side, but for non-Steam retail games that is not possible. GfWL library is surprisingly massive, including games from Rockstar (GTA4), Capcom (SF4), Sega (Universe at War) etc., so it is an important precedent. Note this only applies to DRMed digital distribution - sites like GOG and other offering DRM-free software are the perfect solution in terms of availability.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to legitimately download Steam versions of games outside of the Steam client.

If and when it happens that Valve need to close up shop entirely, then you are going to lose access to installing anything you don't already have installed. There may or may not be any advance warning before this happens; this would depend on the reason they close.

Offline mode should theoretically allow you to keep running previously installed games (as long as it keeps working), at least as long as you don't switch PCs. Outside of that, some games do actually run perfectly fine without Steam, but for those that don't, you would either need a crack or some other way of tricking the game into thinking Steam is running.

A few games - mostly MMORPGs - have you register a separate account, and those games already allow you to download a Steam-free copy from their own site. Other than that, there aren't generally any legitimate ways to recover Steam games as non-Steam games (unless, of course, you bought the game as a Steam Key + DRM-free download).